# How to combine data from 2 sensors in lambda deployed on AWS IoT greengrass?

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-iot, aws-iot-core, aws-iot-greengrass

I have 2 sensors that publish data to Topic1 and Topic2 respectively.

There is a subscription from both devices to the same Lambda function on both the topics.

Example data received by lambda from sensor-

When sensor1 triggered the lambda:
{"sensor1":10}

When sensor2 triggered the lambda:
{"sensor2":20}

I want to write the lambda function logic to check both values together. Example: if sensor1 value is >10 and sensor2 value>10 then publish msg to some topic.

Presently when the lambda function gets triggered, it has data from one sensor only. How can I combine data from 2 sensors into lambda function?